# Result of Oracle's SQL BETWEEN operator

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an `employee` table with following records.

```
EID     ENAME    RESIDENCE
1000    Sanit    Orissa
1001    Sachi    Tamilnadu
1002    Sampath  Karnataka
1006    Pradeep  MP
```

I am playing around Oracle SQL's `BETWEEN` operator.

**Query-1**
`select * from employee where substr(RESIDENCE,1,1) between 'E' and 'T';`

When i check first character is between two characters it is working as expected, but if I pass text into `BETWEEN` operator (See query 2 and 3) I don't understand how does it working?

**Query-2**`select * from employee where RESIDENCE between 'E' and 'T';`

```
**RESULT**

EID     ENAME    RESIDENCE
1000    Sanit    Orissa
1002    Sampath  Karnataka
1006    Pradeep  MP
```

**Query-3**`select * from employee where RESIDENCE between 'Orissa' and 'MP';`

```
**RESULT**

0 rows
```

> I saw oracle documentation says `expressions must be numeric, character, or datetime expressions`. But my queries 2 and 3 is running without any error. Can anyone explain what really happens here?

Comment: In query three change it to between ‘MP’ and ‘Orissa’. For the second query what’s the problem? And these are character expressions, I don’t know what the issue is in the last part of your post.

Answer (score 1):

From the oracle documentation:

> The relational operators compare the two input strings byte-by-byte, similar to the C library routine strcmp(3C). Each byte is compared using its corresponding integer value in the ASCII character set, as shown in ascii(5), until a null byte is read or the maximum string length is reached.

So, in this case 'Orissa' greater than 'E' but less then 'T'.

About your third request. At `between` clause first argument must be a lowest and second one is highest. But in your sample lowest and highest values is opposite.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from employee where RESIDENCE between 'E' and 'T'
```

It checks all the individual characters between `E` and `T` so it's returning

```
Orissa
Karnataka
MP
```

because every character falls between `E` and `T`

```
select * from employee where RESIDENCE between `Orissa` and `MP`
```

here, it doesn't get any name falls between `Orissa` and `MP` so if i change this condition to `Erissa` and `TP` then it will return

```
Orissa
Tamilnadu
Karnataka
MP
```

Answer (score 1):

For query 2 the row with state Tamilnadu is not coming because you have mentioned the condition as:

```
residence between 'E' and 'T'
```

You can say that `'Tamilnadu' > 'T'`, that is why it is not getting selected. Had the condition been:

```
residence between 'E' and 'Tamilnadu'
```

then it would have worked.

Query 3 is not returning anything because you have mentioned the condition as:

```
RESIDENCE between 'Orissa' and 'MP'
```

where `'Orissa' >'MP'`, thus no residence lie in between this range as in between clause, the value before `and` should be less than the value after `and`.

Hope it helps you